# GetChar not waiting for response

Tags: matlab, getchar, psychtoolbox

I'm using psychtoolbox in MATLAB and I want to get a participant to rate the distortion of a string of images from 0-9.
I've tried using GetChar, but when I run the script it doesn't wait for the user to give a response but just moves onto the next screen. 
Any advice on how I can fix this?

```
%using a loop to show images
for k=1:290
texture1(k)=Screen('MakeTexture',w,images{k});    
end
for k=1:145
Screen('DrawTexture',w, texture1(k), [], leftposition);
Screen('DrawTexture',w, texture1(k+145), [], rightposition);
Screen('DrawLines', w, allCoords,...
lineWidthPix, black, [xCenter yCenter], 2);
Screen(w,'Flip');
pause(0.2);
end


%rating text
DrawFormattedText(w,'Rate distortion 0-9','center','center',[255 255  255]);
Screen(w,'Flip');
GetChar();


%press space to finish
DrawFormattedText(w,'press space to finish','center','center',[255 255 255]);
Screen(w,'Flip');


% Wait for a key press
KbStrokeWait;

% Clear the screen
sca;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things going on here: You're only looking for key presses *after* your loop is finished, and you're not storing the result of the key press.

`GetChar` is also messy (you would probably want to call `FlushEvents` to clear the queue, or you might run into (from `help GetChar`):

> If a character was typed before calling GetChar then GetChar will
>   return that character immediately.

One alternative is demonstrated in the example below. It uses `KbWait`, which provides very similar functionality, with a little more work (i.e. converting the key code to a char). Additionally, it implements a 5ms delay between key checks, which helps prevent accidental key bouncing (counting single presses as multiple presses).

This example opens a small window in the upper left corner, displays the current loop iteration in the center of the screen, and waits for a single press to continue. It also records the times of the key presses in `times`.

```
Screen('Preference', 'SkipSyncTests', 2);
[win, rect] = Screen('OpenWindow', 0, [0 0 0], [15 15 400 400]);
Screen('TextSize', win, 20);

answers = cell(1, 5);
times = zeros(1, 5);
ref_time = GetSecs;

for ii = 1:5
    DrawFormattedText(win, num2str(ii), 'center', 'center', [255 255 255]);
    Screen(win, 'Flip');
    [times(ii), key_code] = KbWait;
    answers{ii} = KbName(find(key_code));
    WaitSecs(0.1); %# Wait an extra 100ms for better debouncing
end

times = times - ref_time;

sca;
```